# Gerund: Usage and meaning of "preposition +Being+past participle"

Tags: prepositions, gerunds

I've read in BBC that we use use "being" as a verb-ing. BBC has listed two kinds of usage. What I want to learn here is about the "preposition+verb-ing" form of usage. It has been said that "being+past particle" here is functioning as a noun. But I don't know what kind of meanings it would convey. So, the following are two examples from BBC:

> 1. I look forward to being interviewed on the current affairs programme. (What does "being interviewed" mean?)
> 2. She was afraid of being accused of a crime which she did not commit.
>      (Does it mean: She was afraid of that she was accused of a crime,...)

http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv197.shtml

I think the following are also the examples of "preposition+verb-ing":

> John talks about being helped by a stranger.
>   (Does it mean: john talks about that he was helped by a stranger.)
>
> Before being moved to an apartment, he lived in a hostel.
>   (Does it mean: "Before he was moved to...")
>
> Despite being helped by nurse, he slipped and fell.
>   (Does it mean: despite he was helped by nurse ,...)
>
> What is the risk of being killed in war?
>   (Does it mean: what is the risk of killing in a war?)
>
> What are the chances of being killed by a falling tree?
>   (Does it mean: what are the chances of killing in a war?)
>   Share your experiences of being helped by a teacher.
>
> (Does it mean: share your experiences when you were helped by a stranger?)

Please explain to me the meaning and usage of "being+past particle" when we use it with a "preposition".

Comment: You still don't know what *being accused of (a crime which she did not commit)* means? It is a passive construction. Look up *to accuse*. We *accuse someone of a crime*.

Comment: It seems a passive construction. But how it changed into  'Being accused' ?

Does it mean: She was afraid of that she
She had been accused of a crime which she didn't commmit. ?

"Had been accused of a crime" changed into= "Being accused of a crime"

Comment: I hope the answer of this question would be much mord benificial to All English Learners struggling with 'prepo. + verb-ing(passive)

Comment: The examples are in the _passive voice._ Have you studied the passive voice in English? We form it with the copular verb **be**. One of the forms of **be** is the _present participle_ **being**. With a past participle, we use it to form the passive voice in progressive tenses. We treat things like _being helped_ just like any other noun phrase. In _"John talks about **being helped**",_ the NP is the object of the preposition _about._ It's no different than any other object of a preposition. It's just like _"John talks about **the weather**"._

Comment: @P.E Dent I've studied about passive voice in English. For example: active=stranger helped john.
Passive=John was helped by stranger.
Now, Can't we say=john talks about stranger's help or john talks about helped by a stranger? Why to use "being helped' instead?

Comment: _"John talks about helped by a stranger"_ is meaningless in English. The preposition _about_ can't take a past participle like "helped" as its object. It requires a **noun phrase** like _Being helped._ "Being helped" is a _passive voice_ construction, and it's a _noun phrase_ using the **gerund** (noun form) of the copular verb "be", just as _eating doughnuts_ uses the gerund of the verb _eat_ in the sentence _"John talks about eating doughnuts."_ (Yes, a writer could also write "John talks about stranger's help." But this writer did not.)

Comment: In your examples: active=A stranger helped john. Passive=John was helped by a stranger. Do you see where the verb "be" is used?

Comment: I see the verb 'be' is used between 'helped' and 'joh

Comment: It's clearly understood that the verb 'be' is used between 'john' and 'helped'.

Comment: It's clearly understood that the verb 'be' is used between 'john' and 'helped'. The verb 'be' between them is 'was'

Comment: But,once you told me in https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106047/past-participle-vs-beingpast-participle  that the meaning of 'being+past participle' and 'being+past participle is identical in meaning. And we can omit 'being'. Can't we omit 'being' here in above examples.

Comment: @P.E Dent please respond me

Comment: @yubrajsharma In your other questions that *being Past Participle* is an adjunct in the sentence level. In here it's a complement in Preposition Phrase level.

Comment: Also related: [Could you please explain how to use “preposition+ gerund” in a sentence?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/101527/could-you-please-explain-how-to-use-preposition-gerund-in-a-sentence)

Comment: It seems that when we use passive gerund(which don't have a tense) it's just like infinitive(which don't have a tense either)

To help=To be helped,

helping=being helped